# flutter_svg_provider file from cached images showing some error

Tags: flutter, svg

I was trying to load svg from cached data, and I'm using flutter_cache_manager for caching and flutter_svg_provider for show svg.

here is my demo code,

```dart
Image(
  width: 32,
  height: 32,
  image: Svg(svgCach.path),
)
```

but it shows some error

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving a single-frame image stream:
Unable to load asset: "/data/user/0/com.example.example/cache/libCachedImageData/5d7b41a0-2869-11ee-8a7c-19fa185feb9e.svg".
```